# Borsh Deserialization fails with error "Class undefined is missing in schema"

Tags: typescript, rust, solana

I have been getting an error, "Class 'undefined' is missing in schema", when I try to deserialize a struct in typescript using Borsh.

I am working on a Solana Blockchain, and so I get a serialized data from a Solana Rust program. Here is the struct that I serialize in Rust,

```
/// Define the type of state stored in accounts
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct KeyMaps {

    /// initialize variable
    pub initialized: bool,

    /// mapping between keys and values
    pub account_maps: BTreeMap<Pubkey, BTreeMap<Pubkey,u64>>,
}
```

I need to deserialize it in TypeScript. Here's what I have done so far,

```
class Assignable {
  constructor(properties) {
      Object.keys(properties).map((key) => {
      return (this[key] = properties[key]);
      });
  }
}

//class AccoundData extends Assignable { }
class AccoundData extends Assignable{
  initialized = true;
  account_maps = new Map();

  constructor(fields: {initialized: boolean, account_maps: Map<[32], Map<[32], number>>} | 
undefined = undefined) 
  {
    super(fields);
  }
}

const dataSchema = new Map([
  [
    AccoundData,
    {
      kind: "struct",
      fields: [
          ["initialized", "u8"],
          ["account_maps", 
            {
              // Outter map
              kind: 'map', key: [32],
              value:
              {
                // Inner map
                kind: 'map', key: [32], value: 'u64'
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
     }
  ]
]);
```

Here is where I do the deserialization and get the error,

```
export async function get_keymaps() {

  let nameAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(states_account!);

  const details: AccoundData = borsh.deserialize(
    dataSchema,
    AccoundData,
    nameAccount!.data,
);
```

And this is the error message,

> fieldPath: [ 'account_maps' ],
> originalMessage: 'Class undefined is missing in schema'